# How to load json data from file to a jquery variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json file, that includes:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "red": "#f00",
        "green": "#0f0",
        "blue": "#00f",
        "cyan": "#0ff",
        "magenta": "#f0f",
        "yellow": "#ff0",
        "black": "#000"
    }]
}
```

And I want to put that data and alert it with a jquery code, the .json file is located on localhost in a neighbouring folder

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.getJSON( json path, function( data ) {
    alert(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**This will load the data from the file**

```
var jsonData = {};
$.getJSON('fileName',function(data){
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    jsonData = data;
});
```

Comment: It works, but it puts the whole data with "{[{}]}"etc, into the variable too, and I have to put that into a html table, like an array. (with mustache.js)